# Saving and accessing pointers to strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

Say I get a string from stdin (one line).  Using that line, I would like to create an array of strings from it:

```
char ** array_of_strings
```

I want this array of string to be digits of the line.  So for example, if the line input was this:

```
"aasd1asdf4j  8  98"
```

The array would look like this:

```
["1", "4", "8", "98"]
```

For starters, how would I go about constructing the array in the first place? My idea was to use `isdigit()` to check for when a number started, and make a pointer to there.  Then, when the number is finished, I would change the character value of the first non-digit character to '\0'.  I would continue this process throughout the entire string that I got from line input.  But how can I actually add these pointers to my array_of_strings without creating a segfault because array_of_strings is not initialized?

Is it true that this can be done without allocating any additional memory for the array_of_strings?  I feel like it can because array_of_strings is just holding pointers to strings that are already loaded into memory.

I understand that this is not a code-writing service, but would it be possible to provide some examples about how I could construct such a thing? It makes sense to me in theory, but I have no idea how to even get started in terms of implementing it.  The description I provided above is the closest thing to code I have at the moment.

After the array_of_strings was created, wouldn't it be possible to access its values (which are each of type char *) by using the array syntax? Like: `array_of_strings[0]`

Comment: If you don't know the array size in advance, using `realloc` is an option. If you know an upper limit to the array size, you can use that. If you can scan through the input, calculate the number of digits (without extracting and storing them), you can use plain `malloc/calloc` instead of `realloc`.

Comment: @Evert why would i have to allocate additional memory in the first place, considering that the string (line) which would become the array already exists?

Comment: You'd still need a (dynamically allocated) array of  char pointers to point to the start of each substring? How else do you keep track of the start of each digit string?

Comment: " The description I provided above is the closest thing to code I have at the moment.": perhaps it's worth trying to put it into actual code, using a variety of approaches. Though here, I doubt you can succeed: your pointer to a char pointer (aka string) can only hold one (1) string; hence the need for dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Evert I understand now. Sorry, was not trying to argue with you, I just did not know why.

Comment: @Evert when I try to put it into code, I struggle with how to initialize the pointer in the first place.  Should I initially malloc it to some small number and then keep on reallocing as necessary?

Comment: Not an argument; I was trying to get your line of thought, and I can see how your idea arose. But an array of strings is not the same storage/size as an equally long single string.

Comment: Initialize: that comes back to my first comment, and depends on the practical use case. malloc + realloc is usually done in sizeable chunks, to avoid overhead. If you need minimal overhead, those chunks are very small, but they'll usually be large enough to avoid lots of realloc overhead.

Comment: pointers are relatively small, why don't you just use `char *array_of_strings[256] = {0};` instead and error out if there are more than 255 sequences of digits?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need dynamic memory allocation because you have to allocate space for each pointer. For example, if the string has 150 numbers, you'll need an array of 150 pointers. But if the string has 1 million numbers, you'll need an array of 1 million pointers, each pointing to the correct place inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you make so array_of_strings actually contains pointers to places inside the original string, then you first need to count how much pointers you will need, and not only that, you will need to store length of each substring, or use strpbrk each time you need to read from it.

Another approach would be with realloc, everytime you find a new substring you reallocate (n+1) char pointers, and then allocate appropriate memory size to copy the string to. The code would look something like this (not complete):

```
    char ** array_of_strings = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    char example[] = "aasd1asdf4j  8  98";
    char numbers[] = "0123456789";
    for(char* i = strpbrk(example, numbers) ; i != NULL ; i = strpbrk(i,numbers) )
    {
        int sizeOfNumSubstring = strspn(i, numbers);
        if(array_of_strings == NULL)
        {
            array_of_strings = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
            *array_of_strings = (char*)calloc(sizeOfNumSubstring+1, sizeof(char));
        }
        else
        {
            array_of_strings = (char**)realloc(array_of_strings, (n+1)*sizeof(char*));
            *(array_of_strings+n) = (char*)calloc(sizeOfNumSubstring+1, sizeof(char));
        }

        strncpy(*(array_of_strings+n), i, sizeOfNumSubstring);
        n++;
        i += sizeOfNumSubstring;
    }
```

Comment: You should be checking the return values of `malloc()` etc. for errors; also, the result of `realloc()` should be stored in a temporary variable first, since a null pointer is returned in the event of an error, leading to memory leaks and lost data.

Comment: It is just an example, OP should of course know that some checks should be made.

Answer (score 0):

Without dynamic allocation it is possible to create an array of strings.
In the code below it saves each number that appears in a string, if it is interrupted by a character, we go to the next array and so on

```
#define NUM_STRS 10
#define NUM_CRS  100
char *nums="0123456789\0"; 
char *str="aasd1asdf4j  8  98\0";
char arrstrs[NUM_STRS][NUM_CRS]={0};//array of 200 strings with 200 crs lenght
int nextString=0;
int nextChar=0;
char *pD=str;//pointer to line

while(1)
{
    if(*pD=='\0')/*break if null cr*/
        break;
    int k=0;
    for (k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        if(*pD==nums[k])
        {  
            arrstrs[nextString][nextChar]=*pD;
            nextChar++;
            break;
        }
    }
    /*If k is less than 10, continue in this same string */
    if(k==10)/*If it reaches 10 means that it is not a number*/
    { 
        if(nextChar)/*If something was added...*/
        {           
            arrstrs[nextString][nextChar]='\0';/*close buffer*/
            nextString++;/*go to next string*/
            nextChar=0; /*reset to zero for new string*/
        }           
    }
    pD++;/*increment pointer*/

}
/*testing*/
for(int u=0;u<NUM_STRS;u++)
    printf("%s\n",arrstrs[u] );
```